# python stopped working when using both Tkinter and OS

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

so I have this program below, pretty simple program, that i created so i can listen to random songs instead of having to click on "random" each time i get into media player. now, i made an interface using Tkinter, and the moment i click on the play button, the application runs. but the Tkinter window crushes, i cant click anything else, and when i do it says "python stopped working".

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Tkinter import *
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import os, glob, random
import threading, thread
import time

def skip():
    pass

def start():
    songlist =(glob.glob("C:\Users\idoka\Desktop\Music\*.mp3"))
    random.shuffle(songlist)
    root.quit()
    for x in range (1,file_count-1):

        songnum = songlist[x]
        os.startfile(songnum)
        global currentsong
        currentsong = MP3(songnum)
        global length
        length=currentsong.info.length
        P = Process(target=time.sleep, args=(length,))
        P.start()
        P.join()

        if skip():
            continue

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root.title("Music")
photostart = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\idoka\Desktop\Photos\Icon\Hopstarter-Soft-Scraps-Button-Play.gif")
photopause = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\idoka\Desktop\Photos\Icon\Hopstarter-Soft-Scraps-Button-Pause.gif")

file_count = len(os.walk("C:\Users\idoka\Desktop\Music").next()[2])

startbutton = Button(root, image=photostart , command=start)
skipbutton = Button(root, text="skip", command=skip)
#finishbutton = Button(root, image=photopause, command=finish)

def  main():
    startbutton.pack()
    skipbutton.pack()
    #finishbutton.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i know the program is not perfect, I could program it in a much simpler way possibly, but I'm new to programming and I wanted to do it my way. I'm not asking for a simple one line to write all of this without the bug, but I am asking if there's something small I can do in order for this to not crash.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the line `time.sleep(song.info.length)` and see if it works.

Comment: But I need something to make the next song come only when the one playing is finished. if random songs just pop up thats not what i want. is there any other way i can make the next song "check" when this song is finished or something?

Comment: That call to `sleep` is precisely why your program is hanging. Never call sleep on the same thread that is running your UI. I would suggest you delegate the task of switching songs to a separate thread. Consider taking a look at multithreading operations. Create a thread which sleeps for the duration of the song, calls finish, and then dies.

Comment: I've looked for the past hour on threading, I saw all sorts of stuff but nothing that can help me. i tried threding._Timer but it didnt work. not really sure why.

Comment: It told me "global name "name" not defined. when i did actually define it as global.

Comment: @Shiva I tried adding a thread, and it worked but still crashed. i added this `exit_flag = threading.Event()  
class myClass():  
    @staticmethod  
    def thread_func():  while not exit_flag.wait(timeout=currentsong.info.length):  pass` and then called it

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? I'm not able to see any obvious reason as to why it's not working.

Comment: @Shiva There's no error. it does work. but the program itself, the UI, just stops working, there's a ""name" has stopped working" message by windows and i can click retry or cancel or something like that. the program itself probably takes too much CPU, but it does work well.

Comment: I'm not expert enough with Tkinter to figure this out! 
Do you have access to an Ubuntu/Mac OS computer? Try running it on that and see if the error persists. It could be a windows specific issue.

Comment: @Shiva no unfortunately i do not. i have seen there's an option to do os.fork though. my father is not an expert in python but he does know other languages and he explained it might be what i need. do you know about that? could you explain if you do please?

Comment: `os.fork()` is a wrapper around the C system call `fork()`. While threads run in the same process, calling `os.fork()` creates a new process entirely. While there is more overhead in creating new processes as opposed to new threads, for your application it shouldn't be an issue. To read up about `fork`, look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork
Basically, you call `pid = os.fork()`, and then, `if(pid == 0): ... #child does something` to make the child process do something.

Comment: @Shiva someone online said that `os.fork()` does not exist in windows. I've tried it and it said that the module `os` does not have the attribute `fork`. what I realized is happening is that it's not crashing. the program is waiting therefore even if i use another thread once i call it i can not do anything until its done waiting. is there another thing i can use, that will stop the loop from going, but will let me do other stuff in the meanwhile? is there another library? another anything that you know of?

Comment: It makes sense, because os.fork() is built on top of C's fork(), and C is what GNU/Unix is written in.

As for other libraries, have you taken a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: @Shiva it still crashes. i will edit the question for my new code. will you take a look for why?

Comment: I can try but I can't guarantee anything. The main reason being, I can't execute your code on my machine (because of how specific the problem is).

Comment: @Shiva what do you mean? if you just copy this code and put it onto your machine wont the same error occur?

Comment: Issue being, I don't have a windows PC, or access to music on my desktop!

Comment: Could you check if this works on mac/linux/what ever your PC is? i mean.. you don't have to have music. it just needs to open ANY file and reopen it after a certain amount of time

Comment: @Shiva I accidentally put the thread function inside the `"if __name__ = '__main__': main()` which just ignored the thread. so I know what my problem is... but... how do i fix it?